# how to payara micro port 80

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

Ive tried to run payara micro edition and works on every port except 80.

Im using command

```
java -jar payara-micro-4.1.153.jar --deploy app.war --port '80'
```

ideas?

edit---

payara is not able to connect to 80 port, the stacktrace:

```
[2015-09-12T10:10:20.772-0500] [Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [NCLS-CORE-00019] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1442070620772] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Shutting down server due to startup exception
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bindToChannelAndAddress(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:131)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOBindingHandler.bind(TCPNIOBindingHandler.java:88)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:237)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.bind(TCPNIOTransport.java:86)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener.start(GenericGrizzlyListener.java:185)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GlassfishNetworkListener.start(GlassfishNetworkListener.java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start0(GrizzlyProxy.java:267)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyProxy.start(GrizzlyProxy.java:241)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.createNetworkProxy(GrizzlyService.java:567)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.GrizzlyService.postConstruct(GrizzlyService.java:490)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.postConstructMe(ClazzCreator.java:329)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:377)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:471)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:227)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.RunLevelContext.findOrCreate(RunLevelContext.java:84)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Utilities.createService(Utilities.java:2064)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:105)
        at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ServiceHandleImpl.getService(ServiceHandleImpl.java:87)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.oneJob(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1212)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$QueueRunner.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:1143)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpOneLevel.run(CurrentTaskFuture.java:761)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:560)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture$UpAllTheWay.access$100(CurrentTaskFuture.java:442)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:153)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.CurrentTaskFuture.go(CurrentTaskFuture.java:148)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.proceedTo(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:435)
        at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.RunLevelControllerImpl.proceedTo(RunLevelControllerImpl.java:70)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.proceedTo(AppServerStartup.java:534)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:331)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:228)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:219)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
        at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.bootStrap(PayaraMicro.java:707)
        at fish.payara.micro.PayaraMicro.main(PayaraMicro.java:105)
]]
```

Comment: Please [edit] to add a specific problem statement — "it doesn't work" can be assumed, but *how* does it not work? What error message or incorrect behavior is characteristic?

Comment: If for ex. port `81` runs fine, then ports below 100 are not blocked. If port `80` won't, then it is probably in use by another process.

Answer (score 0):

Start the server as `root` user or `administrator`.